# efficient and light way to post multiple value field in form to aspx web form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

ok, i'll try to better explain the question i am asking: I have an aspx webform that i am using to create an entity, simple data capture. This entity can have many child entities attached to it in a one to many relationship and that are created from the same form. I do not want to use a heavy asp.net component, like a datalist or any custom component to capture those. the way i am currently doing it is that i open a dialog in the page hosting a combobox populated with choices with an ajax call. once the user picks one of the entries and saves, i add an entry to a javascript collection that i use to keep the user choices and display them in a list on the client. when the user submits my form how can i submit this collection and reparse it on the server? I am thinking of using json to store,serialize and then deserialize. is this a good way?

Answer (score 1):

You can post it using the following

```
var postData = function (myobjectinstance){
var objString = JSON.stringify(myobjectinstance);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your url',
    data: objString,
    success: function (){
        alert('did it');
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

};

An then on the server with json.net you can deserialize the json string

```
// You can use JSON.Net
public static void PostMethod(string jsonstring)
{
    var restoredObject  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectType>(jsonstring)

    // do something with your object
}
```

Or you can use the PageMethods in combination with a scriptmanager if you are using a scriptmanager on your page. see this [link](http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/asp-net-ajax-quickstart/introduction-to-ajax/page-methods-in-asp-net/) for more info.

Comment: but i don't want to post it using an ajax call. I want it to be posted  with the whole form

Comment: You can use a hidden field to post the json string. 

<asp:HiddenField runat ="server" ID="hfObject" value="" />


var hfObject = document.getElementById('<%= hfObject.ClientID %>');
hfObject.value = JSON.stringify(myobjectinstance);